# Check if class B is subclass of class A which is located in the same module

Tags: python, oop, subclass

With the following setup of the two files `a.py`

```
#File a.py
import imp
import inspect

class A(object):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mod = imp.load_source("B", "b.py")
    for _, c in inspect.getmembers(mod, inspect.isclass):
        print issubclass(c, A)
```

and

```
#b.py
from a import A

class B(A):
    pass
```

How do I check in file `a.py` if a class found in `b.py` is a subclass of `A`.

The attempt you see in `a.py` results in two `False` being printed. Since `B` is a subclass of `A` how do I check it crrectly?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the following solution:

```
#File a.py
import imp
import inspect

class A(object):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mod = imp.load_source("B", "b.py")

    #self import
    import a

    for _, c in inspect.getmembers(mod, inspect.isclass):
        print issubclass(c, a.A)
```

but still I don't have any idea why it works (while your solution doesn't)